# Font Hinting Issue in Acrobat with Embedding in mPDF

Tags: fonts, pdf-generation, webfonts, antialiasing, mpdf

Running into an issue trying to embed a font in Acrobat via mPDF.

Opening the PDF in Acrobat one Truetype font is distorted (bottom image) no matter the font size at 100% magnification. Unlike Acrobat, in Google's PDF viewer (top image) the same font in the same PDF renders very well.

Printing the PDF the font looks great and zooming in to say, 400%, the font outlines look good too. Other fonts like Calluna display fine in the same PDF.

On the mPDF forum they suggested embedding the entire font and not a subset, but that didn't change anything.

I'm using vector outlines instead of embedding, but I want to see if there is a way to solve this as it's come up before using other fonts.

Wondering if there is any way to account for this within mPDF or via CSS? For Open Source fonts could Font Squirrel fix this?

Update: [Sample File](http://www.suissamesser.com/samples/Font_Hinting_Issue.pdf)

[image: Hinting issue with PDF embedding]

Comment: Which preview exactly are you talking about? Can you provide a sample of such PDFs?

Comment: Sorry my wording isn't as clear as it could be. Just when you open a PDF in Acrobat. The lower image is taken directly from Acrobat.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of such PDFs?

Comment: Sure. I will post a sample PDF shortly.

Comment: @mkl -- Sorry for the delay you'll see I included a link to a sample PDF. Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide on this.